# Surface integral of a vector field in terms of the metric

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, vector-fields, jacobian

**TL;DR**: Is there a nice expression for the surface integral of a vector field?

---

The surface integral of a scalar field $\phi$ over a surface parameterised by $\mathbf{r}(u,v)$ is
$$
\iint_T \phi(\mathbf{r}(u, v)) \ \Bigg \lVert \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial v} \Bigg \rVert \ du \ dv,
$$
which can be rewritten using the vector identity $\lVert \mathbf{x} \times \mathbf{y} \rVert^2 = \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert^2 \lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert^2 - (\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y})^2$ into the *much* nicer and more intuitive expression
$$
\iint_T \phi(\mathbf{r}(u, v)) \sqrt{g} \ du \ dv,
$$
where $g$ is the determinant of the metric $\mathbf g = J^{\text T} J$, and $J = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf r_u & \mathbf r_v \end{bmatrix}$ is the Jacobian.

Now that made me think: *is there a similar expression for the surface integral of a vector field?*

I started with the usual definition
$$
\iint_T \mathbf F(\mathbf{r}(u, v)) \cdot \bigg ( \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial v} \bigg ) \ du \ dv
$$
and worked my way through some identities involing dot products and scalar products, determinants of block matrices, and a bit of matrix algebra to rewrite the integral into
$$
\iint _T \lVert \mathbf F \rVert \sqrt{\det \Bigg(J^{\text T} \bigg(I- \frac{\mathbf F \mathbf F^{\text T}}{\mathbf F^{\text T}\mathbf F}\bigg)J \Bigg)} \ du \ dv.
$$
This is about as far as I could get. I have a feeling that there should be some nice geometric intuition behind this, but I can't quite get hold of it. First of all, the matrix sandwiched between the Jacobians is a projection matrix, right? Its job is to project vectors onto the orthgonal complement of $\mathbf F$, i.e., to zero out anything that points along the vector field at a given point. The determinant of such a matrix is zero, so won't it be zero after transforming by the Jacobian too? Is there something I'm missing here? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you’re trying to calculate the integral $\int_S\mathbf{F}\,d\sigma$ for a surface $S\subset\Bbb{R}^3$ and a vector field $\mathbf{F}:S\to\Bbb{R}^3$ defined on $S$, then the formula/definition remains the same. Fix a parametrization $\mathbf{r}:T\to S$ and calculate as usual $\int_T\mathbf{F}\circ \mathbf{r}\, \sqrt{|g|}\,du\,dv$ (vector-valued integrals being defined component wise for instance). If instead you mean the integral $\int_S\langle\mathbf{F},\mathbf{n}\rangle\,d\sigma$, then this is the integral of a scalar field, so again you already know how to do this.